# Laravel executes 2 queries for a single eloquent create() method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I just noticed, that when I'm trying to execute a single `UserLog::create($data_array)` query.

Laravel executes 2 queries instead.

This isn't causing any problems, I'm just trying to understand why? (as I'm already telling it which columns to set data for in the `$data_array`)

Is there any way to reduce it to a single query?

Here are the 2 queries executed for `UserLog::create($data_array)`:

```
1. select column_name as `column_name` from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'database_name' and table_name = 'user_logs'

2. insert into `user_logs` (...) values (...)
```

Edit: I'm only doing a single `create()` in the page I'm experiencing this, and when I comment out the line, no queries are executed.

Comment: Looks like caching issue? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17781

Comment: @KurtFriars Thanks for the link, but I think the guy is asking for a way to cache that query in there, it's not related to what I'm experiencing here.

Comment: If any one has the same issue later, just use insert, create method always uses 2 queries by default